# How To Find A Label In A Composite

Tags: java, swt, composite

I am trying to refresh a clabel in a composite. However the clabel does not always exist. I need a way to check if exists in the composite. I have tried the `getChildren` class on the composite, and I have been able to use it to find all the `CLabel`'s on the composite,but I can't parse them.

This is what I have so far

```
Control[] childs = comp.getChildren();

for (int i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
    if(childs[i].getClass().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase("CLabel")){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use [`instanceof`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) and then cast it?

```
Control[] children = comp.getChildren();

for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
{
    if(children[i] instanceof CLabel)
    {
        CLabel label = (CLabel) children[i];

        /* Do something with the label */
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for a specific CLabel can I do this with instanceof?

Comment: @Talon06 No, but which criteria do you have to check if the current `CLabel` is the one you are searching for?

Comment: I could either use the name of the CLabel or possibly its contents, but I would like to use the name if possible.

Comment: @Talon06 What is the "name" of a CLabel? I hope you don't mean the variable name that was used when creating it... If you still have a reference to the original CLabel, you can use `.equals()`.

Comment: OK so I used setData to set a value that I could search for and I can now find what I need thanks for the help.